# MySQL Show Profiles duration format?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the `SHOW PROFILES;` command along with `set profiling=1;` to profile my queries, and when I get the profile I get a bunch of durations, and queries and all is well. But I am trying to figure out what format the duration is in. I get a lot of

```
0.00006300
0.00022700
0.00007000
```

small numbers, is this milliseconds? Seconds? Nano seconds? Billionth of a second? Some random other value?

I could not find any documentation on what it is. It looks like seconds but I would like to know for 100%

Comment: well following my intuition given numbers are very small, if they represent nano seconds converting it to seconds is much lower number. So i would guess its seconds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You guessed it, it is in seconds.

Answer (score 5):

It is mentioned in the mysql documentation.. SECONDS

For reference :
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-profiling-table.html

Comment: Thanks for adding an authoritative reference in your answer. This site is just yahoo answers with a link to something.

Answer (score 0):

Command out in seconds. And your result equal microseconds: 63, 227, 70